# @Html.EditorFor in .NET Core like in .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, html-helper, editorfor

There is any option to handle complex nested objects in `editorfor()` in .NET Core like in the .NET framework?

I mean if this is our obj:

```
- obj
-- Nested object 1
--- Nested object 1.1
--- Nested object 1.2
-- Nested object 2
```

In the .NET framework with `editorfor` it would look for editors in `editortemplates` folder for each of object and display all.

In .NET Core, it will only display object that is on top and would not touch the nested objects.

Any solution other than have to write `editorfor` for each nested obj by yourself?

I've tried to make one Html helper `CustomEditor` by myself, but I cannot find any information on how to do that...